# Когда использовать опцию в поле модели null=True?

Tags: django

В полях со строками опцию null надо оставить false. А что в других случаях, где мне нужно пустое значение? 
А то вариант, где я ставлю null=True в полях до тех пор пока при миграции не будет выскакивать ошибка "NOT NULL constraint failed:" меня не устраивает. Хочется нормально понимать